# Client side vs. Server-side Async

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asynchronous, async-await

So I'm trying to figure out if I have this right.  .NET gives us server-side async.  That is the async await.

JS frameworks have their own ways of making async requests.  Whether that's watchers & callbacks or even some have their own await keywords now, there exists the client-side async as well is my point.

So is it true then that you would have both client-side async and server-side async work side by side.  That is, meaning now we can make backend async calls to like a DB, a business layer, etc. without slowing us down as much and at the same token respond quicker to the client-side ascync callbacks as a result?

Node.js (server-side) has async as well.  So I'm just tring to figure out if I have this right, meaning it's good to have both server-side and client-side working together for faster response to the UI.

Comment: There is also client-server-client side async with [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)... But I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to ask - yes both are there and useful... so?

Answer (score 2):

In a WEB environment it's good to have both types of async, but usually for different reasons.

The "client async" is mostly used to make the UI responsive and non-blocking while the "server async" is used to free up resources (threads in this case) to be used by other parts of the system to achieve greater scalability.

---

In a rich client using async can also free up resources which lowers your app's footprint and improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

Client and server are separated by the HTTP channel. They can each be asynchronous but are independent of each other.